# Heroku pg:psql stalls out

Tags: postgresql, heroku

When i run `heroku pg:psql` i get `--> Connecting to postgresql-cylindrical-38664`

and stalls out. Everything is looking good to go, it just gets stuck and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have the same issue in gitbash but when using command prompt, it seems to work.

In command prompt, this works:  `heroku pg:psql --app={appnameinheroku}`.

You can see the apps you have to choose from by running `heroku apps`.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows when using GitBash or Command Prompt you may encounter this issue.

The fix that works only in Command Prompt is: heroku pg:psql --app herokuappname