# Heroku pg:psql says it's connecting but never connects

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am setting up a Postgres database with Heroku, and I am trying to run `heroku pg:psql` in Git Bash to connect to the database. It says it's connecting but it never connects. What is preventing heroku from connecting?

I have downloaded Postgresql 11 on my Windows machine. I've set up a database in data.heroku.com. I've taken the heroku CLI connect command from the credentials of my project and pasted that in. I have not yet modified the source code itself, perhaps that is something that I should do?

I expect it to say something along the lines of:

```
psql (9.5.3, server 9.5.3)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.
```

(this is taken from the guide)

Instead, it just says `Connecting to postgresql-cubed-myid` and it's been sitting like that for around 30 minutes. There's no error code either, it just says that connecting line and sits there. I can't exit git bash without closing the window either, ctrl-c does not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku pg:psql stalls out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49376259/heroku-pgpsql-stalls-out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I fixed it. I was using Git Bash as my terminal, which ended up not working. I switched to cmd and everything was fine.

Comment: Update for 12.2021 - you also need to specify app's name via -a flag.